# Connecting to other MYSQL database than provided by host

Tags: mysql

Ok this is what i am experiencing. I have for example 2 websites (old and new website). The new website is stored on a different host (one.com) the old website on (register.be). If i was developing the new website i was able to connect local (with MAMP) to the database of register.be but now the website is running on the new host i am not able to connect to the database of the old host i always got this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] Connection timed out
```

Could it be that the host isn't allowing me to use another database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go to the company where the database is hosted and give your new website access to use the database, alternatively, try changing your DNS records on the new host to point to the old host's mysql ip address